# Error when call vector's size() for the class field

Tags: c++, class, vector

I stuck with the problem of checking size of an vector in the class. Here is my code:

```
class myclass {
public:
  std::vector<mystruct> v;
};

int main() {

    myclass * a, *b;
    std::cout << a->v.size() << '\n';    
    return 0;
}
```

This code gets segmentation fault. Would someone explain what is the mistake in this snippet? And how could I beat it?

Comment: `a` and `b` point to nowhere. in other words, allocate the objects before invoking `->v.size()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for the pointers; your program behaviour is therefore undefined.

Why not use local automatic variables? `myclass a, b;` will suffice. You'll also need to replace the pointer to member operator `->` with the member selection operator `.`.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you, after the allocation a = new myclass() everything is good now

Comment: @Macaronnos: No, it's not. Read the answer again. In C++, you don't `new` everything, you only do it when you have to (and even then, it should usually be wrapped in a `std::unique_ptr`, if only to keep you from forgetting the necessary `delete`).

Comment: I'd advise against using `new` unless your requirements mean you have no alternative. If you use `new`, you **must** arrange for a corresponding `delete`. Either do that yourself, or use one of the pointer management classes such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do:

```
int main() {

    myclass a, b;
    std::cout << a.v.size() << '\n';    
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, you are using two pointers to `myclass` objects, but they are not initialized, so when you dereference `a` through the *arrow operator*, you invoke undefined behavior.